# Talk to us or Call us

Tags: phrase-choice

Which is the correct usage for an advertisement campaign? Should we use "Talk to us today for more details" **or** "call us for more details"?

Comment: For what it's worth, I can't recommend trying to write ads in a language you're not *very* fluent in. Advertising has to be fairly sophisticated to work well.

Comment: Both are perfectly correct and common... it's really simply a matter of choice. Either way, we aren't really here to copy edit your ad campaign.

Comment: How will the communication happen? *call us* is more likely a phone call, *talk to us* more likely in person.

Comment: @user3169 Yes; and neither suits email very well.

Comment: @Catija a positive attitude on your part will make this a more positive experience for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **call** is to talk on the phone. To **talk** is to speak, regardless of the method (face to face or on the phone or some other way).  The more appropriate verb depends on the method of communication you are trying to convey.